# Mocha + Chai: Continue and try all assertions after failure for the test

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I would like the test runner to continue testing the whole `it` test even after the assertion fails.

```
const { assert } = require('chai');

describe('Test suite', () => {
  it('Test 1', () => { // test fail
    assert.equal(1, 1); // passed assertion
    assert.equal(3, 4); // failed assertion
    assert.equal(5, 6); // failed assertion
  });

  it('Test 2', () => { // pass
    assert.equal(2, 2); 
  });
});
```

If I run this test, `Test 1` failed as expected, but it aborts and don't try other assertions after first failure, printing this error message:

```
  Test suite
    1) Test 1
    ✓ Test 2


  1 passing (6ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test suite
       Test 1:

      AssertionError: expected 3 to equal 4
      + expected - actual

      -3
      +4
      
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/specs/newspec.spec.js:6:12)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

I would like to get the failure information for `assert.equal(5, 6)` as well, can anyone suggest a good way to approach it? Split each assert in each `it` block is not an option as this was just a dummy example, but IRL the test is more complex.